# If a linear operator T maps from a bounded set of X, to a bounded set of Y, then T is continuous.

Tags: linear-algebra

So, I've done quite a bit of fishing about, as well as trying to wrap my head around a simple (and I'd wager that it is simple) proof as to why this is true.
I can work one way, continuity implies continuity, but not the other way.

Anything would be useful, even just a tip where to start.

Answer (score 2):

Start by showing that Boundedness implies Lipschitz inequality which imples continuity.

If $\lambda$ to be the least upper bound of applying $T$ to any $x$ with $||x||\leq 1$. Then for $x_1, x_2 \in X$, $$||T(x_1) - T(x_2)|| = ||T(x_1 - x_2)|| = ||x_1 - x_2|| ||T(\frac{x_1-x_2}{||x_1-x_2||})|| \leq \lambda ||x_1-x_2||$$

since $T$ is linear and $\frac{x_1-x_2}{||x_1-x_2||} \leq 1$. Now let $\epsilon > 0$, and choose $\delta > \frac{\epsilon}{\lambda}$, then $$||x_1 - x_2||<\delta \implies ||T(x_1) - T(x_2)|| < \epsilon$$